# Rails 2.3 paginate_by_sql query slow

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

How do I optimize a paginate_by_sql having complex SQL that has lots of `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY` at the end of query ?

Do I have any other options than `paginate_by_sql`?

our project is using Rails 2.3 and Ruby 1.8 and MySQL.

```
     SELECT Table.name as sql_course_name,Table.id as sql_course_id, 
            table1.name as sql_subject_name, table1.id as sql_subject_id, 
            table3.id as sql_s_c_id, table5.*
       FROM table5
  LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.deleted = false and table2.content_id = table5.id
  LEFT JOIN lessons on lessons.deleted = false and lessons.id = table2.lesson_id
  LEFT JOIN table3 on table3.deleted = false and table3.content_id = table5.id 
  LEFT JOIN table1 on table1.deleted = false and table1.id = table3.subject_id 
  LEFT JOIN Table on Table.deleted = false and table1.course_id = Table.id
  LEFT JOIN table4 on table4.deleted = false and table4.content_id = table5.id
  LEFT JOIN attachments on attachments.deleted = false and attachments.id = table4.attachment_id
      WHERE #{str} 
   GROUP BY table5.id, table3.id
```

Comment: what do you want?....could you please post your codes?

Comment: clicking page 2 of the paginate takes time, 2-4minutes.

Comment: The best anybody can do is optimize the SQL Query you are using. Paginate_by_sql is just a wrapper around that query.

Comment: i have a query something like this
SELECT Table.name as sql_course_name,Table.id as sql_course_id, table1.name as sql_subject_name, table1.id as sql_subject_id, table3.id as sql_s_c_id, table5.*
        FROM `table5`
        left join table2 on table2.deleted = false and table2.content_id = table5.id left join lessons on lessons.deleted = false and lessons.id = table2.lesson_id